# Mysql Can't create/write to file error#13

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-error-1064, mysql-python

I had created a Django view which is returning some data after reading from MySql DB.When i try and fetch around 6000 rows from the Database,everything works fine and the view returns HttpResponse as is expected.However as i try to fetch 7000+ rows i get the following error

```
(1, "Can't create/write to file '/home/nipun/mysql_temp/MYzplJok' (Errcode: 13)")
```

Earlier i thought that the error could be due to space getting exhausted for /temp,so i changed the tempdir setting in my.cnf 

I also ensured that new tmpdir /home/nipun/mysql_temp and it's parent directories are writable by me by changing the ownership.
Although this is not a Django problem,here is the view

```
def query_json(request):
    from django.utils import simplejson
    objects=Publisher.objects.filter(location='ROOM_01',sensor_name='CPU_TEMPERATURE').order_by('-id')[0:9000]

    json = simplejson.dumps( [{"reading": float(o.reading),
                           "timestamp": str(o.timestamp)
                       } for o in objects] )

    return HttpResponse(json,mimetype="application/json")
```

So in the filter changing 9000 to 6000 works fine.

Some more information about the error is provided in the Django stack trace

```
errorclass  
<class '_mysql_exceptions.InternalError'>
errorvalue  
InternalError(1, "Can't create/write to file '/home/nipun/mysql_temp/MYuotga9' (Errcode:     13)")
error   
(<class '_mysql_exceptions.InternalError'>,
InternalError(1, "Can't create/write to file '/home/nipun/mysql_temp/MYuotga9' (Errcode: 13)"))
```

**EDIT**

As per a comment, i tried this on my MySQL prompt

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (i int);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 't' (errno: 13)
```

So it essentially is now an issue of how to allow MySQL to write to temporary directory

Comment: `errno 13` is `EACCESS` (permission denied) on my machine. Are you sure you have set the permissions so the user Django runs as can write the file, not just you?

Comment: When i try and grab 6000 rows or less,it works.So i guess the permissions are fine

Comment: That might be because the MySQL client only has to create a temporary file when you're grabbing more than 6000 rows...

Comment: So i also now did a chmod 777 on /home and it's subdirectories,also specifically on the tmpdir.Still get the same error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is probably a permission issue for the temporary folder that is used by Mysql.

You can find the folder used by Mysql for temp operations in the config file in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as such :

```
tmpdir          = /tmp
```

As you can see, the temp folder in use by default is "/tmp".

Privileges should be :

```
drwxrwxrwt   9 root root  4096 oct.  24 15:39 tmp/
```

So anybody, including the "mysql" user, can use it.
If not correctly set, the following command would do the trick :

```
chmod 0777 /tmp
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: generally it should actually be `chmod 1777 /tmp` (1 sets the 'sticky' bit)

Comment: @Lambart on most modern distro sticky bit is not honored :)

Answer (score 7):

If after giving necessary write permissions to the new tmpdir you're still having the same error - and mysql therefore can't start - you might have [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) enabled. So do :

`sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Of course you can use any text editor other than vim eg nano. Note that `usr.sbin.mysqld` at the end corresponds to what you get by doing `which mysql` or `which mysqld` (with `/` replaced by `.`). When the file is open, you'll see some comments at the top like :

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.mysqld.
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
```

Then put after those comments :

```
/path/to/new/tmp/dir/ r,
/path/to/new/tmp/dir/** rwk,
```

And then do : `sudo service apparmor reload`. Now try starting mysql : `sudo service mysql start` and you should be good to go.

Comment: If it weren't for this answer, I wouldn't have made it past the accepted (and also-helpful) answer's steps.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you for sharing what should be placed in the app armor config

Answer (score 1):

You have configured mysql's tmpdir to point to a directory the server does not have permission to write to.

For small filesorts, MySQL uses an in-memory buffer, but for larger ones uses files on disc (in the tmpdir).

In any case, it is a sysadmin error (not a programming error) setting the MySQL tmpdir to point to a unwritable directory.

Comment: I even tried http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/using-tmpfs-for-mysqls-tmpdir still keep on getting the same error

Comment: It is nothing to do with the user which Django runs under. The MySQL server needs to be able to write to its temporary directory. You can test this easily from the mysql command line by creating a temporary table (e.g. CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (i int); )

Comment: I am not able to create temporary tables,tried this on MySQL prompt mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (i int);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 't' (errno: 13)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving mysql user access to the directory via below command:

`chown -R mysql:mysql /home/nipun/mysql_temp/`

This worked for me (:

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your sql account have File Priviledges
2. Outfile into temp directory. example 'INTO OUTFILE /tmp/yourfile' Or directrory that mysql has access
3. For download the file within your site, just make symlink that '/tmp' into your public html folder

note : if you cant delete your file because of permission issue, then your filename must be unique.